# Arrays en donde se intercambian elementos

Tags: java

Necesito crear un método por el que se reciba un array de String y se intercambien sus elementos dos a dos. Esta es mi tentativa pero no produce los resultados esperados. ¿podríais, por favor, decirme en qué me equivoco??
Adjunto mi codigo junto con la entrada y salida esperada

Entrada "uno", "dos, "tres","cuatro"
Salida esperada "dos","uno","cuatro","tres"
Salida recibida "dos","dos","cuatro","cuatro"

```
public static void intercambio(String a[]){
    
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(i==0 || i%2==0){
            a[i]=a[i+1];
           
        }
        else{
         a[i]=a[i-1];
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: que quiere decir no reproduce los resultados esperados? que resultado esperabas? que resultado recibes? que quiere decir intercambiar los elementos de dos en dos?

Comment: Perdona, he editado mi pregunta donde indico los resultados esperados.

Comment: Y si es un array impar?

Comment: En el ejercicio que me han puesto no se contempla esa opción. Las entradas siempre tienen que ser de un array par.

Comment: Bueno.. entonces, sabias que tu for puede ir de dos en dos? con lo cual, agarras la posicion 0.. intercambias entre la posicion 0 y la 1.. y luego vas a la posicion 2... haces lo mismo.. y asi hasta terminar el array... probalo... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la primera iteracion al cumplirse que `i%2==0 siendo i=0` el valor en esa posición se pierde ya que la reemplazas por la que le sigue para evitar eso podrias hacer uso de una variable auxiliar que capture ese valor y se asigne en la condicional `else` ,o podrias aplicar lo que te indican en lo comentarios ;)

```
public static void intercambio(String a[]){
    String aux=null;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            aux=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1]; 
        }
        else{
         a[i]=aux;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: También podrías hacer la operación de una así: `[ a[i], a[i + 1] ] = [ a[i + 1], a[i] ]`

Comment: @ArianJM esa seria una mejor respuesta... Esta no es mala.. solo no es optima...

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void intercambio(String a[])
{    
    String tmp = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2)
    {
       tmp = a[i];
       a[i] = a[i + 1];
       a[i + 1] = tmp;              
    }    
}
```

Haces un **ciclo for** e incrementas la **variable i** de dos en dos, y ya dentro del **ciclo for** haces el intercambio de posiciones en el arreglo usando para ello una **variable temporal**, muy parecido a lo que se hace en el método burbuja.